# Add a random number of -1 or 1 to each row which contains an odd number using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Hope this is not a duplicate, since this is such a basic question, but I couldn't find a solution in any other question.

I like to add -1 or 1 randomly to every odd number in the column mpg using dplyr. But when I use my solution it either adds -1 or 1 to all rows. I want that `sample()` takes a sample of -1 or 1 for each row new.

Here are my two results that I get in the moment:

[image] [image]

Here is my current code:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars2 <- round(mtcars,0)
mtcars3 <- mtcars2 %>% mutate(mpg2 = case_when((mpg %% 2) != 0 ~ mpg + sample(c(-1,1),1), TRUE ~ mpg))
```

Any help showing me where I've gone wrong is much appreciated.

Comment: The crucial thing you are misunderstanding is that `mpg + sample(c(-1,1),1)` is only evaluated once, and `case_when` uses the elements of that vector when the condition is `TRUE`. And that is always `mpg + 1` or `mpg + -1`.

Comment: Just change `sample(c(-1,1),nrow(mtcars2),replace = TRUE)`.

Comment: I understood that ```mpg + sample(c(-1,1),1)``` is only evaluated once and that this is the problem, but I didn't know how I can change the code so that ```mpg + sample(c(-1,1),1)``` evaluates for each row new. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify the `size` as `n()` in `sample`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars2 <- mtcars2 %>% 
  mutate(mpg2 = case_when((mpg %% 2) != 0 ~ 
         mpg + sample(c(-1,1),n(), replace = TRUE), TRUE ~ mpg))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually tried n(), but got an error, because I didn't had replace=TRUE. This was an easy solution, but this answer would not have occurred to me and it also didn't occur to me to search for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should just add `rowwise` to apply the function in every row:

```
mtcars2 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    random = sample(c(-1, 1), 1),
    mpg2 = case_when(
      mpg %% 2 != 0 ~ mpg + random,
      TRUE ~ mpg
    )
  )
```

result:

```
# A tibble: 32 x 13
# Rowwise: 
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb random  mpg2
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1    21     6   160   110     4     3    16     0     1     4     4     -1    20
 2    21     6   160   110     4     3    17     0     1     4     4      1    22
 3    23     4   108    93     4     2    19     1     1     4     1     -1    22
 4    21     6   258   110     3     3    19     1     0     3     1      1    22
 5    19     8   360   175     3     3    17     0     0     3     2      1    20
 6    18     6   225   105     3     3    20     1     0     3     1     -1    18
 7    14     8   360   245     3     4    16     0     0     3     4     -1    14
 8    24     4   147    62     4     3    20     1     0     4     2      1    24
 9    23     4   141    95     4     3    23     1     0     4     2      1    24
10    19     6   168   123     4     3    18     1     0     4     4      1    20
```